# typing dynamic path in typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm using typescript and I don't know how to type object named `updates` because it has got dynamic path based on some variable. Have you got any suggestions?

```
    const updates = {};
    updates[`/posts/${selectedCategory}/${Date.now()}`] = data;
```

Comment: Please consider providing a [mre] that demonstrates your problem, and only your problem, when pasted as-is into a standalone IDE.  Maybe [this](https://tsplay.dev/w8LrVw) is what you want, but I can't tell because I don't know what `selectedCategory` or `data` are, and I don't know what your intended use of `updates`.  Some code that defines everything you are using and demonstrates valid and invalid uses of `updates` would be very helpful here.

Comment: I'm getting a error `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '`/posts/${string}/${number}`' can't be used to index type '{}'`

Comment: Please [edit] the code in your question to include the necessary code so that when I paste it into a standalone IDE I see the same thing as you.  Please review the guidelines for what makes a [mre].  Did you look at [this potential solution](https://tsplay.dev/w8LrVw)?  Is that what you want?